# Nodejs,redis autocompleter, closures

Tags: javascript, node.js, autocomplete

*Code rewritten

I'm trying to convert antirez's autocompleter to javascript to use it with node.js.

I can't pass the closure Problem. Maybe someone can help me out.

I see where the problems are but can't figure out how to solve them.

The while loop is firing, the break is not correct and won't work etc.

Code:

```
var acp = {

  vars: {

    dict     : false,
    count    : false,
    prefix   : false,
    rangeLen : 10,
    start    : false,
    results  : false,
    range    : false,

  },

  sendResults: function(){
    console.log(acp.vars.results);
  },

  getzrank: function(){

    redis.zrank( acp.vars.dict, acp.vars.prefix, function( err, start ){

      acp.vars.start = start;

    });

  },

  getzrange: function(){

    redis.zrange( acp.vars.dict, acp.vars.start, parseFloat( acp.vars.start+acp.vars.rangeLen-1 ), function( err, range ){

      acp.vars.range = range;

    });

  },

  createAutocomplete: function(){

    while( acp.vars.results.length != acp.vars.count ){

      acp.getzrange();

      acp.vars.start+=acp.vars.rangeLen;

      if( ! acp.vars.range || acp.vars.range.length == 0 ) { break; }

      for ( var i in acp.vars.range ){

        var minLen =  Math.min(i.length,acp.vars.prefix.length); 

        if( i.substr( 0, minLen ) != acp.vars.prefix.substr( 0, minLen ) ){ 

          acp.vars.count = acp.vars.results.length;

        }

        if( i.substr( 0, i.length-1 ) == "*" && acp.vars.results.length != acp.vars.count) {

          acp.vars.results.push( i.substr(0,-1) );

        }

      }

    }

    acp.sendResults();

  },

  init: function(dict,prefix,count){

    acp.vars.range   = false;

    acp.vars.dict    = dict;
    acp.vars.prefix  = prefix;
    acp.vars.count   = count;
    acp.vars.results = [];

    acp.vars.start   = acp.getzrank();

    if( ! acp.vars.start ){ acp.sendResults(); }
    else{ acp.createAutocomplete(); }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The break statement is outside the scope of the while loop since its nested in the anonymous function. Not sure if that solves your problem.

Comment: I know. I guess that could be the solution. But how to fix it?

Comment: I have rewritten the code. Without fixing the error but maybe this makes it easier for others to help.